# How to send a string from one form to a datagridview on another form?

Tags: c#

How do I send a string value from one form2 to the `DataGridView1`'s last row on the main form.

What is the simple way to this?

Comment: low quality question... What do you have tried? Code-Examples?

Answer (score 1):

You will need some properties in your window/form. 
Something like this:

```
public class WinStringGen : *Window or Form*
{
...
    string myStringValue = "";
    private void save()
    {
      myStringValue = "value"; //set your value
    }
    public string MyStringValue
    {
      get{return myStringValue;}//Contains your string
    }
...
}
```

Now you can get the Value like this:

```
WinStringGen win = new WinStringGen(); //init window
win.showDialog(); //open window. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

string myValue = win.MyStringValue; //get the value
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your event that is going to call form1 :

```
form1.datagridview1.rows[form1.datagridview1.rows.count-1].cells[0].value = mystring;
```

where `mystring` is the string you want to pass.
for further infos please comment.